# User XP Data Isn't Being Written To JSON File

Tags: json, discord.py, bots

I'm this is my first time ever using JSON, so it might be something obvious. I'm trying to make a Discord Bot that gives users XP and levels for messaging, and to do this I need to write the data to an external JSON file. I couldn't get it to work, so I followed a tutorial, copied it perfectly, and yet it still doesn't write to the JSON file, so I'm at a dead end.

My Pathing: `/Desktop/TGFY Bot/cogs`

`/TGFY Bot` holds my main bot file 
`/cogs` holds my leveling.py cog and my users.json file

leveling.py is below

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json

class leveling(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_message(self, message):
            with open('users.json', 'r', encoding = 'utf8') as f:
                user = json.load(f)
            try:
                with open('users.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as f:
                    user[str(message.author.id)]['exp'] = user[str(message.author.id)]['exp'] + 1
                    lvl_start = user[str(message.author.id)]['level']
                    lvl_end = user[str(message.author.id)]['exp'] ** (1.5/4)
                    if lvl_start < lvl_end:
                        user[str(message.author.id)]['level'] = user[str(message.author.id)]['level'] + 1
                        lvl = user[str(message.author.id)]['level']
                        await message.channel.send(f'{message.author.name} has reached level {lvl}')
                        json.dump(user, f, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
                        return
                    json.dump(user, f, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
            except:
                
                with open('users.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as f:
                    user = {}
                    user[str(message.author.id)] = {}
                    user[str(message.author.id)]['level'] = 0
                    user[str(message.author.id)]['exp'] = 0
                    json.dump(user, f, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(leveling(bot))
```

My users.json file only has `{}` in it

When I run my bot I don't get any errors, but when I send messages, no information is stored to users.json

Comment: Is the indentation off in your question? Or is the on_message listener actually inside the init function?

Comment: Try printing something just before opening the json file to write

Comment: @Kelo The indentation was off, but I fixed it, which gave me a new problem. It couldn't find users.json in the file pathing, so I move it to `/TGFY Bot`. That worked and it was recognized, but I still have the same issue of nothing writing to users.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, except for one line

```py
except:
    with open('users.json', 'w', encoding = 'utf8') as f:
        user = {} # This empties your dictionary whenever a new user has sent a message
        user[str(message.author.id)] = {}
        user[str(message.author.id)]['level'] = 0
        user[str(message.author.id)]['exp'] = 0
        json.dump(user, f, sort_keys = True, indent = 4, ensure_ascii = False)
```

Simply remove that line and your code should work fine.

Next time, please try to understand more of the code from tutorials to know how to apply them to your use cases.